# Consulta comando Find en Linux

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos, find

Ante el enunciado: "Escriba un comando que copie en el directorio ***updated*** todos los archivos ordinarios del directorio actual (pero no sus subdirectorios) que hayan sido accedidos a lo largo de las últimas 48 horas", el comando que he pensado es el siguiente

`find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -atime 2 -exec cp {} /home/itb/Escritorio/updated \;`

pero lo he probado y no consigo que copie los archivos al directorio ***updated***. No entiendo muy bien el uso de los **{}**.

Answer (score 0):

Ya casi lo tenias. Debes modificar el parámetro `-maxdepth 0` por `-maxdepth 1` así:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -atime 2 -exec cp {} /home/itb/Escritorio/updated \;
```

**Explicación:**

**-maxdepth 0** solo busca lo que le pides en la misma línea del comando, no en el directorio actual.

Tal como dicen en [su página `man` en castellano](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-extra-0.8a/man1/find.1.html):

> `-maxdepth 0' significa que sólo se aplicarán las comparaciones y
> acciones a los argumentos de la línea de órdenes.

Si por ejemplo tuvieras un archivo llamado `texto.txt` en el directorio actual, para que lo reconociera con el `-maxdepth 0` tendrias que escribirlo así:

```
find texto.txt -maxdepth 0 -type f -atime 2 -exec cp {} /home/itb/Escritorio/updated \;
```

Para que realmente empiece a buscar en el directorio actual debes poner `-maxdepth 1` en su lugar.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración! Al final he conseguido que funcione el comando.

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -atime -2 -exec cp {} /path \;

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro.  Si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta debes marcarla como aceptada para que no quede pendiente eternamente.  En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) explican como hacerlo y en este [otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) el porque es importante hacerlo. Gracias por colaborar con el buen funcionamiento del sitio.